# Double digits recursion explaination

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem to understand how recursion parameter calculated, which explained in this question [Java recursion and integer double digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226947/java-recursion-and-integer-double-digit). The implemented code looks like this:

```
public static int doubleDigits(int i){

        if (i == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
           return doubleDigits(i / 10) * 100 + (i % 10) * 10 + i % 10;
        }


}
```

With the result if int i = 1234:

```
 11223344
```

I tried to debug the code, but having difficulties to understand, what goes on.

I have checked many examples and, I can understand most of the cases how recursion works but not in this case.

I would like to get a  easy-understandable explanation how recursion works in this case.

Comment: `doubleDigits` gets called recursively until it meets the break condition.

Comment: User a pencil and a paper, set `i=12` and begin drawing things. This method helps you understand recursion in 100% of the times.

Comment: I will try with the pencil and paper, sounds like a good idea.haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion always works by solving a smaller problem and then adding to that solution (or combining smaller solutions).

```
doubleDigits(i / 10)
```

doubles the digits of the number having all the digits of the original number except the last one.

Then it is multiplied by 100 to make room for the remaining two digits, which are added with `(i % 10) * 10 + i % 10`. `i % 10` is the last digit of the input number, and it is added twice to the output number.

```
doubleDigits(1234 / 10) * 100 + (i % 10) * 10 + i % 10

112233                  * 100 +       4  * 10 +      4         = 11223344
```